# Le mot « seule » sert-il à mettre l'emphase sur un autre mot dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens, philosophie

J'ai lu l'extrait d'un texte dans un article du portail lexical du CNRTL, concernant le mot  « [absolu](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/absolu) ». L'extrait est de *Destutt de Tracy* et date de 1805.

> ... toutes nos connaissances ne sont toujours que celles de nos manières d'être et des lois qui les régissent, qu'elles sont toujours relatives à nos moyens de sentir, qu'elles ne sauraient jamais être absolues et indépendantes de ces moyens, et que tous ceux qui se proposent de pénétrer la nature intime, l'essence même, des êtres, abstraction faite de ce qu'ils nous paraissent, veulent une chose tout-à-fait impossible et absolument étrangère à notre existence et à notre nature, puisque nous ne pouvons pas même savoir, **si les êtres ont une seule qualité autre que celles qui nous apparaissent**.

J'ai des doutes sur la partie marquée. Je crois que l'auteur en cette partie pensait à deux types de qualités : celles que nous observons dans les êtres (i.e. dans les choses) et celles non-observables. Exprime-t-il tout simplement un doute sur l'existence de qualités non-observables ? Le mot « seule » me paraît un signe d'emphase…

Même si ces qualités non-observables n'existent pas, ça ne dit rien sur la possibilité de découvrir « la nature intime des êtres » ; peut-être peut-on réaliser quelque méthode *absolue* de traiter les qualités que nous observons *relativement* à nos moyens… Je crois alors que je n'ai pas bien compris quelque chose dans cette phrase, elle paraît illogique… Il n'y a aucune raison de mettre en emphase les qualités elles-mêmes, quand il s'agit en fait de nos connaissances limitées…

Peut-être que le mot « seule » sert à autre chose ? Pourrait-il mettre l'emphase sur un mot différent, non « qualité » ?

Comment: @jlliagre Merci beaucoup pour les corrections, elles ont été instructives. Mais… ce extrait ne concerne pas le mot « absolu » ; c'est l'article de dictionnaire sur le portail lexical qui le fait. J'ai utilisé le mot « voix » par erreur (voir le mot « voce » en italien); le mot correct est « article ».

Comment: J'ai remis *article*. Je me doutais bien que la langue originale était l'italien à cause du faux-ami *parole*. Je n'avais pas compris *voix*, je pensais à une erreur pour *voie* (*via*) mais ça ne collait pas...

Comment: Ah, on ne parle pas italien en Russie ? ;-)

Comment: C'était de l'humour, d'où le smiley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour moi, sauf erreur : l'auteur utilise l'emphase ici pour mettre en relief le fait que l'on ne peut pas observer une qualité non-observable effectivement en opposition à celles que nous observons. On ne peut donc pas prouver leur existence ni leur inexistence. Étant donné qu'on ne peut pas observer ce qui est non-observable, on ne risque pas de pouvoir pénétrer la nature intime, l'essence même, des êtres, abstraction faite de ce qu'ils nous paraissent.

Il suffirait d'une seule (unique) qualité non-observable pour que ce soit une preuve et que l'on puisse alors prétendre pouvoir pénétrer la nature intime, l'essence même, des êtres, abstraction faite de ce qu'ils nous paraissent.

Comment: Le raisonnement, si je le comprends bien: «il y a peut-être une qualité qui ne nous apparait pas du tout» => «il est très difficile d'ésperer de pouvoir pénétrer la nature intime des choses etc, car cette nature peut-être ne nous apparait pas, ça va contre notre condition». Alors, le mot «seule» en fait sert à indiquer que une seule qualité de ce genre suffit pour faire la conclusion. Très clair, merci beaucoup! J'attends un jour, puis j'accepte votre réponse.

Comment: Ce n'est pas exactement ça : "on ne peut pas savoir s'il y a une qualité qui ne nous apparaît pas du tout"  => "pénétrer la nature intime, l'essence même, des êtres, abstraction faite de ce qu'ils nous paraissent" = "impossible" & "étrangère à notre existence et à notre nature". Seule sert effectivement à indiquer que une seule qualité de ce genre suffit pour faire la conclusion. Si on pouvait observer une qualité de ce genre alors la conclusion de l'auteur serait inverse : il est possible pénétrer la nature intime etc...

Comment: J'ai pensé. Puis, j'ai pensé plus. Au présent, je ne vous comprends pas : on ne peut pas observer ce qui ne nous apparait pas parce que « nous observons X » et « X apparait à nous » sont des synonymes ! Non ? Donc, l' « intrigue » du raisonnement est differente de ce que vous dites…

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûre de comprendre, mais « nous observons X » et « X apparait à nous » ne sont pas des synonymes. « nous observons X » veut dire que l'on regarde attentivement X et donc qu'il est visible. « X apparait à nous » veut dire que X devient visible pour nous et donc observable mais peut ne pas être observé. Si X n'est pas visible pour nous, on ne peut alors pas le regarder attentivement.

Comment: Je me réfère à votre phrase : « si on pouvait observer une qualité qui ne nous apparait pas … » La prémisse est toujours fausse, indépendamment de nos connaissances, non ?

Comment: Tout à fait, la prémisse est toujours fausse, de part notre nature.